# Rails copy record from staging to production

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a project where there are two environments **staging** and **production**. The marketing team creates records on staging environment and wait for client approval. If client approves, then they have to create the same record on production environment which is a re-work.

I would like to move the staging record to production. To do that, I created a separate model on my `models/ad_to_production.rb`, in there I established the connection to the production database. The original model name is `Ad`.

The problem is that, the `ad` record that I'm trying to copy to remote database has some images. I'm not sure how to send the images over to the production server. This is what I've done so far:

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  title           :string
#  image           :string
#  destination_url :text
#  created_at      :datetime         not null
#  updated_at      :datetime         not null
end


class AdToProduction < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :"production_db"



  def copy(staging_ad)
    self.title = staging_ad.title
    self.image = image if staging_ad.image.present?
    # skip codes
  end 
end
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: That seems like a strange workflow. Have you considered having a bit flag indicating approval or a staging area (PrePressAd) for ads in production? That when when the ad is approved you can either flip the bit or move the image from the `pre_press_ads` to `ads`

Answer (score 0):

It seems the images are urls which represent the files' paths, and the image files are stored in the file system. You can just copy those files to the new server with rsync or scp tools.

Comment: I thought of it, but its not a wise decision maybe. Because each image has multiple versions.

Comment: @Emu How about copying the root images file path?